# It is possible to Integrate Activiti with Drools rule engin

Tags: drools, activiti

I am working on a project and trying to evaluate Drools vs Activiti. 
I know there is jBPM support but my client needs Activiti for managing the business flow and I need to use rule engin for evaluating some cases.
So is it possible to integrate drools and activity. Any pointer would help.

Comment: It is possible, but personally I don't think it's a good idea. Usually drools is used in this context to produce one or more outcomes based on a subset of process instance variables. This can be modeled as a system task that calls an external service, which can be implemented using Drools, but this will be an implementation detail that your process can be unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the Gitter channel this is totally possible. 
I will recommend you to do a small PoC (Proof of Concept) to really understand the details of it. People usually underestimate the complexity of a Rule Engine like Drools. Don't get me wrong, I love Drools, but I recommend you to check the docs and one of their books ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the chapter in Tijs Rademaker's book "Activiti in Action". It describes the drools integration for version 5.x of Activiti very completely. The concepts are still valid for Activiti 6 as well.